# Mysterious CSS vertical space

Tags: html, css, xhtml

From this simple html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .t1 {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .popup {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
    .hint {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 20em;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid green;
      padding: 0.5em;
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
    .list {
      padding: 0px;
      padding-left: 1em;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- properly layout -->
<div style="height: 10em;">
  <span class="t1">MyObject o = www.mycompany.project.ObjectFactory.</span>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="hint">
      <ul class="list">
        <li>NewSimpleObject(int x);</li>
        <li>NewComplexObject(int x, int y);</li>
        <li>NewComplicateObject(int x, int y, intz);</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>  <!-- no idea why, but ending space is required for proper layout -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- incorrect layout -->
<div style="height: 10em;">
  <span class="t1">MyObject o = www.mycompany.project.ObjectFactory.</span>  
  <!-- mysterious vertical space appear here -->
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="hint">
      <ul class="list">
        <li>NewSimpleObject(int x);</li>
        <li>NewComplexObject(int x, int y);</li>
        <li>NewComplicateObject(int x, int y, intz);</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- <div>&nbsp;</div>  -->
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the result:

[alt text http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/6224/resultrendering.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/6224/resultrendering.png)

The result is similar across browser. So I believe this is not a browser bug.

Where does the vertical space between the text-line and the popup-hint in the second rendering come from ?  And how can the **<div>&nbsp;</div>** solve this problem ?

**UPDATED:**

Conclude from *Richard M* answer. Box with no content has no dimension (with an exception of [Inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)). The **<div>&nbsp;</div>** make "popup" dimension exists.

The better solution, according to Richard, is to use inline instead of inline-block. Since [the vertical dimension of inline is the same regardless of its content existence](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)

For some reason I don't know yet, the **margin-top: 1em** is no longer necessary when switch to "inline"

**UPDATED 2:**

OH NO.. This issue cannot be concluded yet. The change that *Richard M* suggest (use `inline` and remove `margin-top`) would work only with Webkit Browser (Chrome, Safari)  On IE and Firefox , the `popup` box align to the left rather than to the text line.

The first sample in the question (inline-block & non-empty content) is probably the most reliable option for now.

**UPDATED 3:**

Conclusion !  The true cause of this issue originate from the fact that `non-inline` block with no content has no dimension.  *Richard M* suggest using `inline` to avoid this issue.  Unfortunately, I've found this solution inconsistence across browsers.  I came up with another option in opposite direction, using `inline-block` with forced dimension via `height: 1px;`  This work correctly in any browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .t1 {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 0em;
    }
    .popup {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0; 
      position: relative;
      width: 0;
      height: 1px;  <!-- force vertical dimension -->
    }
    .hint {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      margin-top: 1px;  <!-- compensate for the setup dimension -->
      width: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .list {
      padding: 0;
      padding-left: 1em;
      margin: 0.5em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- properly layout -->
  <div style="height: 10em;">
    <span class="t1">MyObject o = www.mycompany.project.ObjectFactory.</span><!-- 
      whitespace is not welcome
    --><div class="popup">
      <div class="hint">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>NewSimpleObject(int x);</li>
          <li>NewComplexObject(int x, int y);</li>
          <li>NewComplicateObject(int x, int y, int z);</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!--
      whitespace is not welcome
    --><span>(1, 2, ...</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.hint` div has a 1em top margin to "push" it down below the line of text, however in your second instance your `.popup` div doesn't contain anything (as absolutely positioned elements take up no space). An inline-block div with no content has no height or width and sits on the baseline of a line of text. So, you are "pushing" off the bottom rather than the top of the line, and hence the additional 1em vertical space. I don't really understand why you're using inline-block, inline would work just as well given the content of the div is absolutely positioned.

---

In response to your question edits: Using display inline as I suggested should work, but you need to set the left and top values of your absolutely positioned `.hint` div to zero. Also, you'll need to remove your `<div>&nbsp;</div>` element otherwise you'll end up with a line break where it occurs (because it's not inline).

Comment: You mean I should use <div style="display: inline"> ?

Comment: Yes, change to display inline and remove the 1em top margin and your two cases will be laid out be the same.

Comment: The empty "inline-block" have no height. But the empty "inline" share the same height as its preceding..  Is that the proper takeaway for this lesson ?

Comment: Yes, that is the case as far as I understand it. The height of an inline element is equal to the line-height of the containing element, while an inline-block element has no intrinsic dimensions.

Comment: Just notice that your vote is decrease. I have no idea why, however Richard M answer is absolutely correctly explain the cause of this issue. (Although, his latest suggestion is not actually work :)

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the fact that the `div` with the class `popup` is not the one with the `position: absolute`, but its child, `hint`.

From the browser's perspective, the `popup` div, when containing only `hint`, has *no content*, and thus, no dimensions. The `<div>&nbsp;</div>` gives it content and causes the `hint` popup to start properly on the top edge of the `div`- but why that is, still escapes me, even though I'm sure there is a perfectly logical explanation for it :)

Comment: I believe that popup having no content or dimensions is causing the problem. You can correct it by leaving the <div> there or by setting the height of .popup explicitly (It can be any small value. I tried 10px and it worked fine.)

Comment: @takteek true. What I find fascinating is why a popup with *no* content will cause the starting point for `hint` to move down 1 line, but a popup *with* content will not. This is a really tricky edge case. Anyway, it can be fixed using the methods you mention.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the real intention is:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

instead of just:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Wow.. clear:both make both sample work ! No idea why. Would you please explain more ?

Comment: it's pretty much like adding a carriage return after the floating objects above it, which means you're clearing your workspace below them.

Comment: Hmm.. from Pekka answer, it looks like ANY content inside "popup" will do. "clear:both" shouldn't have any effect in this case.

Comment: @rockjock I believe there are no "float" involve in my case.

Comment: but <span> and .popup are inline blocks, so you really don't have to specify float. They're already floating.

Comment: It's floating but it's definitely not a "float". :)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your margin-top on the **hint**. You can set it to a negative value if needed to correct the alignment.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really solve the mystery of why the rendering differs, does it?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the margin-top: 1em; the second layout will work.

EDIT: replace **margin-top: 1em;** with **overflow: auto;** and you don't need the div anymore.

Comment: But the first one will fail then.